# Are the Peano Axioms necessary to prove $\forall{x}\exists{y}\ x<y$ (LPL 16.41)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, formal-proofs

[This is problem 16.41 in Barwise & Etchemendy's "Language, Proof, and Logic".]

The only premise given is $\forall{x}\forall{y}\ (x<y \iff \exists z (x+s(z)=y))$

From this, it asks for a formal proof of:  $\forall{x}\exists{y}\ x<y$

This is easy if we can appeal to the Peano Axioms; however, none of them listed as premises in this exercise.

The instructions for this section say: "Use [proof software] Fitch to construct formal proofs of the following theorems from the Peano Axioms plus the definition of <.  In the corresponding Exercise file, you will find as premises only the specific axioms needed to prove the goal theorem."

Moreover, on 16.41 there is an explicit hint: "Notice that the Exercise file contains the definition of < but none of the Peano Axioms!  So although this follows from Exercise 16.40 [$\forall x x<s(x)$], you won't be able to use your proof of that that[sic] as a lemma."

I'm stumped and confused.  I apparently can't use any Peano Axioms, but if that's true, how am I supposed to use the given premise containing the successor function?  Don't we need at least a few PA to define how that object behaves under addition?

Is this proof possible as described, or what am I missing?  Hints only, no solutions, please!

Comment: Ok, here's a hint: Why not take $y$ to be $x+s(x)$? (You don't need to know anything about the function $s$ other than that it's a function.)

Comment: It would help to know the definition of $<$ provided, but Alex’s approach is the likely answer, or $y=x+s(0).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The OP gave the definition of $<$ in the second line of the question. $x+s(0)$ works, but only if we have a constant symbol $0$ in the language, which wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The full axioms of PA are *not* necessary to prove $\forall x\exists y(x<y)$. The question is whether the premise given in line 2 of the question is sufficient to prove this sentence, and the answer is yes. In particular, it's fine for the symbols $+$ and $s$ to stay "meaningless" here.

Comment: Ok, I got it now.  Thank you! I think I did have the right answer earlier, but I had been justifying the introduction of a +s(a) = a+s(a) with the illegal FO validity checker rather than the legal = introduction rule, so it was marking it wrong.